# Why does this print the wrong thing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class, variables

why does this print "So it must be: test test" and not "So it must be: hello it's me"

```
class bob():
    subjectTemp='test'
    levelTemp='test'
    def setSubject(function_subject):
        bob.subjectTemp=function_subject
        print(bob.subjectTemp)
    def setLevel(function_level):
        bob.levelTemp=function_level
        print(bob.levelTemp)
    def join(subject=subjectTemp, level=levelTemp):
        print("So it must be:", subject, level)



bob.setSubject("hello")
bob.setLevel("it's me")
bob.join()
```

Comment: It won't print either since it'd probably complain that you're passing too many arguments to the functions. you need a [mcve]

Comment: the `join` default arguments are the class variables of `bob` which are both `'test'`.

Comment: Because you bind `subject=subjectTemp` to the default value `subjectTemp` had at the time.

Comment: This is also not nearly how you're supposed to use classes. Yes, it "works" as far as it does because reasons, but there's basically no point to using a class here.

Comment: @deceze I needed to use classes cause this is just an example of what I needed, in reality, the class contains more, furthermore, it is a specific type of class required for the implementation of a library.

Comment: In the end, the solution was so simple, and I was doing things in a needlessly complicated way. I was facing challenging (actually challenging) problems before and I went blind forgetting the basics of coding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The immediate "problem" is that this binds at function definition time:

```
def join(subject=subjectTemp, level=levelTemp):
```

The value of `subject` will be the value of `subjectTemp` at the time the function was declared, and it won't change. See ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/476) for details.

The bigger problem is that this isn't how you use classes at all. You want something like this:

```
class Bob():
    subject = 'test'
    level = 'test'

    def set_subject(self, subject):
        self.subject = subject
        print(self.subject)

    def set_level(self, level):
        self.level = level
        print(self.level)

    def join(self):
        print("So it must be:", self.subject, self.level)

b = Bob()
b.set_subject("hello")
b.set_level("it's me")
b.join()
```

Answer (score 1):

subjectTemp and levelTemp have the default value.

You can write:

```
class bob():
  subjectTemp='test'
  levelTemp='test'

  def setSubject(function_subject):
      bob.subjectTemp=function_subject
      print(bob.subjectTemp)
    
  def setLevel(function_level):
      bob.levelTemp=function_level
      print(bob.levelTemp)
    
  def join():
      print("So it must be:", bob.subjectTemp, bob.levelTemp)

bob.setSubject("hello")
bob.setLevel("it's me")
bob.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

The default values are evaluated, once, at function definition. This is a classic problem that new Pythonistas stumble upon when using mutable arguments such as lists — but this is another instance of the same gotcha.

You can read more about default arguments in the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values).

In particular: "Important warning: The default value is evaluated only once".

Edit: This is the technical explanation for what you ask about, but please read others' comments and answers here. This is a peculiar way to use Python classes which will probably trip your leg down the road. Please google 'Pythonic code' and 'idiomatic code'.